# Placing indistinguishable objects on a indistinguishable shelve

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways can we place $10$ books on a bookcase with $3$ shelves if the books
are

(a) indistinguishable copies?

(b) all distinct?

For a, would it simply be $10!$ ?

Comment: The answer is not $10!$ for either, because if you think about it, the fact that there are $3$ shelves surely matters and must figure in the answer.

Comment: a)$\binom{12}{2}$

Comment: See the table on page 3: http://www.elcamino.edu/faculty/gfry/210/DistributeBallsBoxes.pdf.

Comment: For (a), you are looking at the ways to sum up 10 adding $x_1 + x_2 + x_3$ (the number of books on each shelf). Take a peek at [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count the ways to arrange 10 books and 2 dividers.

In both cases the dividers are effectively indistinguishable.  It doesn't matter what order the dividers come in.  The books are placed on the three shelves depending on whether they are before, between, or after the dividers.

(a) Count how many permutations there are of the following 12 symbols representing 10 indistinguishable books and 2 dividers.
 $$\star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \,\star \mid\; \mid$$

There are ${12\choose 10,2} = 66$ ways to do this.

**If** the shelves are indistinguishable (even by location) we have to consider the way they can be rearranged.

When two shelves contain identical patterns of books the arrangements can be divided into groups of $3$ which are considered identical (ie: equivalence classes).  Because the books are all indistinguishable, this happens the same number of books are on two shelves.  So there is just $6$ group of $3$ arrangements which are identical for this reason ($18$ arrangements in total).

When the three shelves all contain a distinct patterns of books (ie: different numbers), the arrangements can be separated into groups of $3!$ which are considered identical.  There are $\frac{66-18}{6} = 8$ such groups.

So the count of equivalent classes is: $6+8= 14$

---

(b) Count how may permutations there are of the following 12 symbols representing 10 distinct books and 2 dividers:
$$ABCDEFGHIJ\mid\;\mid$$

There are $\frac{12!}{2!}=239,500,800$ ways to do this.

**If** the shelves are indistinguishable (even by location) we have to consider the way they can be rearranged in equivalent ways.

When two shelves contain identical patterns of books the arrangements can be divided into groups of $3$ which are considered identical.  Because the books are all distinguishable, this only happens two shelves contain no books.  So there are $10!$ such groups (by counting the permutation of all books on the same shelf).

When all the three shelves contain a distinct patterns of books, the arrangements can be separated into groups of $3!$ which are considered identical.  There are $\frac{\frac{12!}{2!}-10!3}{3!} = 38102400$ such groups.

So the count of equivalent classes is: $10!+\frac{\frac{12!}{2!}-10!\times 3}{3!} = 41,731,200$

Comment: You have to take care here because the bookshelves are indistinguishable, therefore the permutations  $\star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \,\star \mid\; \mid$ and  $ \mid \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \mid$ are indistinguishable, for example.

Comment: @FooBarringoo  Bookshelves should be distinguishable by location, but it seems it was asked in the title after all.  Edited the answer accordingly.